# Android black screen with Unity app in subview

Tags: unity, android

I've exported an Unity app/game I have made to Android Studio. In Android Studio I made a layout and within it I have a framelayout. However, when I run the app the framelayout is completely black, why?

Here is my Java code:

```
public class UnityPlayerActivity extends Activity {
    protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer; // don't change the name of this variable; referenced from native code

    FrameLayout fl_forUnity;

    Button bt_groen, bt_gul, bt_sort;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBX_8888); 

        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
        if (mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getBoolean("hide_status_bar", true)) {
            setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }


        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        this.fl_forUnity = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fl_forUnity);

        this.fl_forUnity.addView(mUnityPlayer.getView(),
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


        this.bt_groen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_groen);
        this.bt_gul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_gul);
        this.bt_sort = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_sort);

        this.bt_groen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Main Camera", "ReceiveRotDir", "G");
            }
        });

        this.bt_gul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Main Camera", "ReceiveRotDir", "Y");
            }
        });

        this.bt_sort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Main Camera", "ReceiveRotDir", "B");
            }
        });

        mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:rowCount="3"
                android:columnCount="10">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dip"
        android:id="@+id/fl_forUnity"
        android:background="#00FFFF"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Grøn"
        android:id="@+id/bt_groen"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bt_sort"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bt_sort"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bt_sort"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gul"
        android:id="@+id/bt_gul"
        android:layout_column="9"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bt_sort"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bt_sort"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bt_sort"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sort"
        android:id="@+id/bt_sort"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fl_forUnity"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I had a similar issue a little while back. Have you preloaded any assets in your player settings? For me preloading assets is what caused the problem

Comment: What do you mean by preloaded?

Comment: In your player settings there's an option to preload assets, which I found caused my game to throw a black screen on Android. If you haven't found it then you're probably not using it though TBH. The manual page is here if you're interested :-) https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html

Comment: Ok.... What could then be the problem?

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer: add `android:process=":UnityKillsMe"` to your unity library activity tag in manifest.

And also, we should implement `onWindowfocusChangedListener` for sure:

```
void OnWindowFocusChanged(){ m_UnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(hasFocus);}
```

My code: It worked

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private UnityPlayer m_UnityPlayer;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // Create the UnityPlayer
       m_UnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
       int glesMode = m_UnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
       boolean trueColor8888 = false;
       m_UnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
       LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
       layout.addView(m_UnityPlayer.getView(), 0, lp);
       m_UnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(true);
       m_UnityPlayer.resume();
   }
   @Override
   public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
   {
       super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
       m_UnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
   }
   @Override
   public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       m_UnityPlayer.pause();
   }
   @Override
   public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       m_UnityPlayer.resume();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       m_UnityPlayer.quit();
   }
}
```